# how to let an object spread out in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want an object spread out like .animation like this http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and than especially the demo with animate block 1 and block 2 this:

```
$( "#go1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#block1" )
    .animate({
      width: "90%"
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 3000
    })
```

but in as3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the TweenMax library from Greensock.
http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

You would do something like this:

```
TweenMax.to(objectToAnimate, time, {scaleX:0.9, scaleY:0.9});
```

Comment: Your value for the spread won't work the way you think it will. Instead, it will set the width to .9px. To set to a percent width, they can do `.9 * parentContainer.width`. Or if they are using Flex, use `{percentWidth: 90}` instead. Additionally, the user should use TweenLite unless there is a specific reason to use TweenMax (TweenMax adds more size to the build and is slightly slower at times)

Comment: thanks @josh - I meant to make that scaleX, not width. Fixed it above.